# How to modify the auto-generated bundles path using the Angular CLI

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I want to serve my Angular 2 application from a relative path, however I'm running into issues with how the angular-cli generates the **index.html** page.

The CLI inserts script references but because a leading slash isn't included, the html `base` tag doesn't prefix the requests. EX of current cli output:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
```

What I want is for the CLI to allow me to customize this path. EX:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myapp/inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myapp/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myapp/main.bundle.js"></script>
```

Is this possible with the CLI? The server that is hosting these files cannot use these default paths the way they're specified in the index.html page.

Comment: Unclear: the paths it generates are relative, not absolute. They would be absolute if they started with a `/`. What would you like to achieve?

Comment: All your server has to do is expose the contents of `dist/`, that seems pretty straightforward. Where the `base` is should only matter as far as routing is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the parameter [*deploy-url*](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#user-content-options) param in angular-cli.json. If you put text 'app' to this param, you get paths like 'app/inline.bundle.js' in your index.html file.